# VBA listbox.rowsource crashed after a while

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I Link a listbox to a named range in the same worbook. But sometimes after a while I get a unknown error.

Extract of my code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Listbox1.RowSource = "namedrange0"
    ListBox2.RowSource = "namedrange1"
End Sub
```

I open this userform from a another userform and it works fine, but after a while I get `Runtime error 8004005 Cant set RowSource, unknown error`

Anyone got something similar?

Comment: Gives me a type mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Try with the full path for `listbox` objects.

```
 UserFormX.Listbox1.RowSource = "SheetX!namedrange0"
 UserFormX.ListBox2.RowSource = "SheetX!namedrange1"
```

Comment: Is it okay if you I take a look at your file?

Comment: Sorry, employee does not allow this.

Comment: Can you add the name of the form before the listbox name? 
something like Form1.Listbox1.RowSource

Comment: I did try this but I still get the error. The First, which direct to the userform with the error has the command Me.hide, can this cause trouble?

Comment: Try commenting the Me.hide out.

Comment: Can you try using list instead of rowsource. I can't really help you if I can't see the entirely of your code. Perhaps if you can reproduce the error in a new spreadsheet I would be able to help ya.

Comment: Sadly not, I think it has maybe something to do with the `RefEdit ` controls inside vba. So I just use addItem method and hopefully it will fix the problem